# Wordpress: Need a plugin to create a section in the dashboard to recall the output in templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created in my header template a div with inside text that I need to be editable from the dashboard and not from the template. So I was imagining it would be like putting a code into the template and having a section in the dashboard (like for posts, pages, etc) that gives you a text area and when you edit it will automatically change into the template.

Does anyone know if a plugin exists that does this?

Thanks! M